# Nautilus crashes after upgrade (12.04LTS->14.04LTS)

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 14.04, crash

i've upgraded my 12.04LTS Ubuntu to 14.04LTS. Everything installed fine, however my 'Nautilus' is behaving weird. It crashes every time i try to open a folder..

My whole desktop is blank.

When i press `Files` it restarts the file manager (showing stuff on my Desktop and opening a new window with the files). But when i press any item (file or folder) it crashes everything, showing nothing (no desktop files or folders and window goes away).

I've checked many 'solutions' that didn't work for me, for example:
[Nautilus doesn't work.... from command or from unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351950/nautilus-doesnt-work-from-command-or-from-unity)

Any suggestions what i can do?

Things i've already done:

- reinstalled nautilus
- installed some packages (python-nautilus i believe?)
- fully (+purged) removed nautilus and installed it again
- something with samba? idk lol

BTW. I have also an SSD with a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 that works totally fine!

### Edit:

This guy has a similar problem to me: http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=339938

Permissions are also fine (root:root, chmod=755)

I ran nautilus -c which did gave me a specific error:

`running nautilus_self_check_file_utilities
running nautilus_self_check_file_operations
running nautilus_self_check_directory
running nautilus_self_check_file`

`FAIL: check failed in nautilus-file.c, line 8334
      evaluated: nautilus_file_get_name (file_1)
       expected: eazel:///
            got: eazel:
running nautilus_self_check_canvas_container`

Looking now how to fix, anyone suggestions..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally managed to fix the problem. I've checked so many websites and the bugtracker of Ubuntu Nautilus. Spent the whole day looking for the cause; i'm not even sure if i found the 'real' cause. I even was unable to login again...lol.. :).

For the people who are experiencing the same problem; here's what i think is the problem: there were duplicates of extensions in nautilus (maybe caused by the upgrade?):

```
/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0
/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0
```

Even when i did: `sudo apt-get remove --purge nautilus`. It still stayed there (and maybe somewhere else). So what i did is:

`dpkg -l | grep naut*` or `dpkg -l | grep nautilus`

and manually removed all libraries listed until there's nothing left.

**A very important note:** Your system might get messed up! Don't reboot before you installed nautilus et al again.. (When reboot, you might get what happened to me: 'Failed to load session' and virtual console didn't work..! More info down)

Now, when you've REALLY removed **everything**, you can reinstall nautilus again:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Then check your list again:

```
dpkg -l | grep naut*
```

It should show the same list as before (without duplicates). And your nautilus is fixed! 
Reboot to be sure that everything works fine..

### If your reboot failed 'Failed to load session':

This happened to me, because i was too aggressive with deleting the libraries.. hehe. I accidently removed some core files of ubuntu.

Use **CTRL + ALT F2** (or F1,F3,F4,F5,F6; F7 returns back to the login). This will open the *virtual console* where you can try to re-install the packages you accidently removed.. (for me it was `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop`; this will -i think- reinstall the deleted core packages again)

### Reboot failed + virtual console failed..

If you can't enter the *virtual console* --> reboot and press `SHIFT`. This will give  you a list -*safe-mode*- where you can load the terminal from there. I selected one of the safe-modes on the top list. This will return a list where you can do some things. In our case we needed a wireless connection -loading takes a LOT of time- and the terminal.

Overall i had a great time and learning experience; this was a good moment to learn some new bash commands and about Ubuntu. I love ubuntu 14.04 :D!

Answer (score 0):

I followed the solution here to kill running nautilus processes and it worked.

[Nautilus not opening up, showing GLib error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788182/nautilus-not-opening-up-showing-glib-error)

I've been experiencing a similar problem today, only I couldn't open nautilus at all. So I'm wondering if this is due to some recent update clash.

This isn't a likely solution, but at least it allows me to carry on as normal.

First thing to try is sudo nautilus in a terminal. If it works, then it may mean that there is something wrong with active nautilus processess for your current user.

To be able to restart nautilus properly, do the following:

See what nautilus processes are running :
ps aux | grep nautilus
Kill all nautilus processes you see :
sudo kill PIDNUMBER
Restart nautilus :
nautilus -q