# Nautilus crashes on file/folder drag, Icon issues 14.04

Tags: nautilus, compiz, crash, segmentation-fault, drag-and-drop

Ubuntu 14.04, Unity.  Nautilus crashes without error message when I try to drag any file/folder.  Left click and hold on anything, the second it moves a millimeter, Nautilus crashes/closes.  Additionally, the "open with" icons and Unity Dash icons are individually all different sizes. Also the prntScr key stopped working properly All this may be a compiz issue vice Nautilus.  Please let me know of any analytic information that may help.

Additionally, if I press Ctrl in an open nautilus window... nautilus closes.. :(

Additionally, I actually cant type in an open nautilus window (like to jump to something)

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)` is the error in terminal when it crashes

Additionally: all my radial and check boxes are gone

Additionally: unity control center crashes when themes are selected

Comment: I have found a solution here, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218488

Comment: I'm not sure what that means... I deleted the /Templates folder from ~/.local/share/nautilus but it didn't fix anything... thanks anyway.

Comment: you can try this also http://askubuntu.com/questions/460258/nautilus-crashes-after-upgrade-12-04lts-14-04lts it is a rare problem actually.

Comment: I only have the 3.0 extension there.. I guess I can try the fix though (wipe and reinstall...) I'll post back Thanks.

Comment: Nope.. didn't work... :(

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/64244/nautilus-crashes-when-accessing-some-folders

Comment: Google it!there are various solutions available.

Comment: I have been Googling it for 2 days now. Nothing has worked.  last suggestion didn't work either.

Comment: Open 'nautilus' through terminal and report if any error is coming or not.

Comment: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when I tried to move anything or pressed a key

Comment: Is there any path namely /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/ ...If there is move it to /tmp by sudo mv /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/ /tmp.And then type nautlius.

Comment: OK, I have to go out for an hour or so, I will when I get back. Additionally, I've just realised that I have a home folder in my applications directory that I've never noticed before... double click and it opens my home folder in the normal location... is all of this a messed up symlink or an accidental copy paste maybe?

Comment: And Moving the python extension folder didn't work

Comment: Not so rare. I have the same problem, including missing check boxes, crashing on changing theme, PrintScreen problems - basically everything exactly as described. I have tried re-installing nautilus and also anything compiz related without luck. This seems to be a very specific problem, yet the only solutions offered are for general nautilus crashes. Only thing that I can add is that I get this error in the terminal:
segfault at 0 ip (null) sp 00007fff43b721d8 error 14 in nautilus[400000+157000]

Comment: Tried installing nemo in replacement of nautilus, but that suffered the same problem with the same error message - Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem, albeit belatedly. Like TheByteSmasher, having no luck myself or finding any solution through countless searches, I re-installed. I backed up everything up and left my home directory in place during the re-install. Everything was working fine afterwards. Problem solved. But it seems this may not be necessary.

Upon re-adding all my old PPAs and most of my old software and updating, the problem returned exactly as it was before. This was highly frustrating having spent the weekend backing up and re-installing to solve this problem!

Luckily I was able to backtrack and find out what had been upgraded and I eventually located the culprit:

**libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0**

Somehow my version of that file had been updated from Utopics stable version **libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:2.30.8-1** to the development version **libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:2.31.1-1**

I wasn’t able to downgrade that package but using the following command I was able to locate the PPA that had upgraded this package:

```
apt-cache policy libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
```

This showed me the PPA that package belonged to. I then used PPA Purge to revert all the changes made by that particular PPA

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo ppa-purge [ppa to be purged]
```

This reverted all the changes and restored everything back to normal, everything from checkboxes to nautilus working.

I hope this helps someone else as this is a deeply frustrating problem, not able to use the file manager in any useful way is a nightmare, let alone being unable to change theme, open anything that also uses nautilus (startup disk creator would crash on disc image selection, and many others too).

I am not sure whether the solution can be achieved without a re-install, but I would have thought it likely and definitely worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure it out so for a fix I reinstalled Ubuntu from a live CD in root and boot... Since I have different partitions for root, boot, home and swap, none of my data was changed. I had to reinstall all the apps and tweaks I had previously, but since home was unaffected, all my settings, bookmarks, app state etc remained as it was.