# Ubuntu 14.04- Click on directy closes the main window

Tags: 14.04

I just have upgraded my system from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. I am facing a weird sort of problem, whenever, I click on any directory or file in /home or in any drive. Instead of, opening that directory the system somehow closes the main directory. I try to explain here, if you still have confesion in understanding the isuue, for instance, I have ten directories in /home/Ahmad/ in which one has name 'abc'. When I click on abc directory, the system closes the home windows. It happens so fast and I even can not to copy paste anything. I'll apreciate if some suggest me the solution for this. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/64244/nautilus-crashes-when-accessing-some-folders

Comment: No, this issue is not same as posted in the question which you have refered. I tried both solutions suggested over there with no luck.rm -rf ~/.nautilus
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-open-terminal

Comment: Ok. For future reference, just add information of what you already did and what has failed into your question. And have you tried rebooting machine after doing rm -rf ~/.nautilus  ?

Comment: And for now you could install another file manager to deal with files, until the issue with nautilus is solved. You can do 'sudo apt-get install dolphin' .

Comment: Yes, I rebooted the system after running this command rm -rf ~/.nautilus. Thanks for suggesting an alternate solution. But I have to fix the built in file manager.

Comment: There is a self-check for nautilus. Can you run `nautilus -c` in terminal and tell us what it says ?

Comment: Worst case is that you may need to reinstall the nautilus, which is shown here : http://askubuntu.com/a/460746/295286

Comment: Followings are the results of the command. running nautilus_self_check_file_utilities
running nautilus_self_check_file_operations
running nautilus_self_check_directory
running nautilus_self_check_file
running nautilus_self_check_canvas_container
running nautilus_self_check_file_utilities
running nautilus_self_check_file_operations
running nautilus_self_check_directory
running nautilus_self_check_file
running nautilus_self_check_canvas_container