# Nautilus does not open (Segmentation fault )

Tags: nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I am not really used to Linux.
When I started Ubuntu today, there was a message of internal error
that caused Nautilus to not launch.

When I use terminal  `sudo nautilus`,

```
(nautilus:2694): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Also, the desktop does not respond to the right mouse button click.

I even do not know how to get more information on the source of error.
I tried to remove nautilus and reinstall

`sudo apt-get remove --purge nautilus`

`sudo apt-get install nautilus`

It does not solve the problem.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please post more information.  Try running Nautilus from the terminal.  Posting screenshots of the problem would also be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/351950/nautilus-doesnt-work-from-command-or-from-unity

Comment: Thanks @ThatGuy. I followed the steps in the link. However, it did not work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you trying to run Nautilus as `root`?

Comment: If I type 'nautilus', it only gives 'Segmentation fault' with no additional information. Thus I tried 'sudo nautilus' and got some more message.

Comment: Ok, running Nautilus via sudo, would account for the error you're seeing.  Try using `gksudo` instead of `sudo`

Comment: Try rebooting & see if nautilus is ok. If so it's just something that occasionally happens in 16.04, can also be 'fixed' by killing nautilus in system monitor. Stop using `sudo nautilus` command, doing so is a bad idea..

Comment: Thank you for comments. The problem persists. Because I don't know the source of error or how to resolve it , I may have to reinstall ubuntu.(fortunately my all data are in dropbox.).